# Best practice for modifying data in a method from the view in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm writing an angular app to display reports which can open and close with [bootstrap collapse accordions](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse). I decided to add some view specific values to my report object for the accordion, like this:

```
var report = [{
    "testName": "Cool Test",
    "successful": true,
    "openAccordion": "in" //this was added for bootstrap's sake to say whether this test in the report is collapsed or not
}]
```

I figure that way I can just update my model and the two-way databinding will collapse and uncollapse things for me.

What I want to do now, though, is I want to add buttons that do this stuff. For example, I want a button that sets all the tests in a report to `"openAccordion":"in"` to open all the tests, and another that sets them to `"openAccordion":""` to close all the tests.

I figured out I could write a service that has functions hanging off it like this:

```
bookApp.factory('report', function() {

    this.getReport = function() {
        [...]
        return report;
    }

    this.setAccordions = function(report, setting) {
        [set all tests to setting's value ...]
    }

    return this;

});
```

I think I like that, but then what's the best way to use an `ng-click` to kick that `setAccordions` function off? Do I have to set that service function as a function off my `$scope` in my `ReportCtrl`, or can I call that function off the service directly from the view?

Comment: It has to be a scope variable in your controller to access it from the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the factory function directly, but first the controller has to bind it to your controller's scope:

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, report) { 
    $scope.setAccordions = report.setAccordions;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
<button ng-click="setAccordions(true)">Set to true </button>
```

Comment: Makes sense. Seems a little strange though. If I had a bunch of controllers and I wanted to reuse the same service function in all of them, that would be a lot of repetitive code, and I've read that it's considered very very bad practice to bind methods to `$rootScope`. I'm going to give this a little bit of time before accepting to see if anyone else knows any alternative ways to do it.

Comment: You aren't binding to $rootscope.  You're right that would be bad.  You're binding to the controller scope.  And it's actually a plus from a readability standpoint that each controller needs to include the service- it makes it clear to any reader of your code which controllers depends on that service.  But you're right- it does mean extra code.

Comment: I just meant that the only alternative to that repetitive code that I know of would be binding to $rootScope, which is considered bad.

Comment: Yea, good point.  And the repetitive code, since it's small and is just establishing a binding, is considered good from a readability and maintainability standpoint. But you're right that it's going a little against the DRY (don't repeat yourself) grain.  But many consider it a net gain.